# Passing data between the fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

### I am trying to pass the `data` from `edittext` of one fragment to `textview` associated with other fragment

---

I am following static way of passing data between fragments

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click to send data to next Activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    Button button;
    EditText textedit;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textedit=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

                f2.setName(textedit.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
package com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

    View view;
    TextView txtview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);

        return view;
    }


    public void setName(String Name){

        txtview=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtview.setText("Hello:: " +Name);

    }


}
```

---

### [Edit]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        class="com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        class="com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    Button button;
    EditText textedit;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textedit=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                FragmentManager FM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

                f2.setName(textedit.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

**Log**::

```
10-30 14:37:32.900: D/AndroidRuntime(460): Shutting down VM
10-30 14:37:32.900: W/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities/com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  ... 11 more
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities-2.apk]
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-30 14:37:32.940: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  ... 20 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.usingtwofragmentsfornavigatingbetweentwoactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

[image]

**How to resolve this ?**

Comment: Try to use sharedPreferences, or save the Values in the MainActivity or use a Singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment
```

you are not this importing fragment from the support library and your device is older pre Android 3. It should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

also in your xml change

```
android:name
```

with

```
class
```

Comment: My android device is 2.2 ...... but i have used supporrt fragment in all activities ..... please have a look , i have even posted the manifest....... And can you point me out which activity i am not importing the support package

Comment: I saw that you used the support package in Fragment2. Check for Fragment1

Comment: and instead of getFragmentManager() you have to use getSupportFragmentManager(); All have to be from the support package. You can not mix things all around

Comment: and you got the same exception? Try with clean and rebuild

Comment: Actually the error was that i had used regular activity to extend rather than FragmentActivity in mainActivity.java so ... i solved it

Answer (score 2):

Inside `Fragment1` onclick of `button1`, do something like this:

```
FragmentManager FM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

            f2.setName(textedit.getText().toString());
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I have reflected all the changes ... please have a look at the edit in the question

Comment: Actually the error was that i had used regular activity to extend rather than FragmentActivity in mainActivity.java so ... i solved it

Comment: @smriti3: I think my answer was right,as I have posted about `getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I had already selected the answer for blackbelt ....... so [+1] upvote for your sharing the info & helping me :) :)

Comment: @smriti3: It is not matter of upvotes or reputation.It is just to help other developers who face similar problem as yours and look at the correct answer which was worked for you.